# I need to call PHP file in JavaScript and store the output of PHP file in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

file in JavaScript and store the output of PHP file in JavaScript variable
I have tried it soo much but no use I am new to webtechnologies 
Iam doing this as my mini project 
Any answer from you is very helpful
So please kindly help me.....

Comment: `I have tried it soo much but no use` - Please supply your existing code so we can help resolve the problems with it.  We're not here to simply write your code.

Comment: You can use an AJAX request to retrieve the output of your executed PHP

Comment: Please always include any code that you already have. I believe you are looking for a Javascript AJAX call to a PHP page. Then you can get the return data from the PHP page and use it in Javascript. [Read here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, make sure the PHP you are going to get data from will only printing the data you want passed in as the Javascript variable. If that data is in a variable called `$output`, make sure it is in JSON. You can convert PHP arrays, strings, and objects to JSON by running the json_encode function. This is something similar to how your last line should look:

```
print json_encode($output);exit;
```

In your javascript, you can access this PHP file, and convert it to a javascript in the following ways. If you are using the library JQuery, you can use AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which is a powerful function for writing simple requests for this kind of data:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/path/to/php/file.php'); ?>",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(data) {
    javascriptVariable = $.parseJSON(data);
  }
});
```

If you are interested in simplifying the process of DOM manipulation (identifying elements in HTML, and writing functions around events to change/animate elements of a web page), you can learn more about JQuery from W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

However, if you are looking to accomplish the same task in pure Javascript, you can do the following:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', '/path/to/php/file.php', true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var javascriptVariable = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
         }
    }
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

The best way to accomplish what you want depends on the audience. If you need every last drop of CPU power, you will want to use pure Javascript, as JQuery is just a library of extra helper functions that will use extra processing power to run. If developer time is more expensive, JQuery runs smoothly even on older hardware, and might even help you understand the flow of writing web scripts.

Either way, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to offer a JSON object to your front-end.

A simple example:

```
<?php

$myData = array(
    'a dog',
    'a fish',
    'a cat'
);

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
var myData = JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($myData); ?>');    

//Print out dog?
console.log(myData[0]);
</script>
```

Of course, this is a very easy method to do it, and you can fancify it all you want but this is the basics.